# Node: HTTP Server Not Starting

Tags: node.js

following a tutorial on node. Trying to copy-paste this code, to setup a web server.

I think I am placing a semicolon wrong. Please help me out.

Error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:352
    throw e;
    ^

SyntaxError: Error parsing C:\Users\USER\Desktop\nodeserver\package.json: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 223
```

```
{
  "name": "nodeserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"

require("http").createServer((inRequest, inResponse) => {
 inResponse.end("Hello from my first Node Web server");
}).listen(80);
}
```

Tried to follow a tutorial on node, copying the code from the book as instructed.

Comment: Why are you putting JS code in the package.json?!

Comment: Which tutorial are you following ?
What is the contents of your `package.json` ?